# How to place split elements into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

If I have a string of names separated by commas, how do I separate them all and place them as individual elements in a new array?

For example--

```
var str="How,are,you,doing,today?";
document.write(str.split(","));
```

I'd like to put each of those elements straight into an array. What's the way to do this?

Comment: What are you learning from that it uses `document.write`? Lose that book/site and find something else.

Comment: Google search tip: if you add " mdn" after a Javascript keyword or function name (e.g., "split mdn") the first search result is almost always the Mozilla Developer Network doco page about that keyword or function

Comment: @epascarello—likely the OP is just using `document.write` as a convenient output method.

Comment: Correct, but I did originally copy the example from w3schools, entertainingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign them to a variable when you split them:

```
var new_array = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about how to you just declare it as an array, you would do that like this:

```
var strArray = ["How","are","you","doing","today?"];
```